# Virtual PC: Why do I have to re-logon on every window resize?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am running a Windows XP virtual machine in Microsoft Virtual PC on Windows 7. I have the integration features installed on the guest machine.

Every time I resize the virtual machine's Window, I get the Windows XP logon screen (the one that appears when you leave your computer for a defined amount of time, and need to enter your password to get back to windows).

How do I turn that off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Virtual PC now works with remote desktop as protocol of choice. If you change resolution, it breaks of connection and reestablishes new one. During that reestablishing you get password prompt.

Only choice I see is telling it to remember password. Downside is that it will never ask for password again so it is not a solution when you need some basic security.